# Peculiar behavior in custom DoubleBinding (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76507114/minimum-of-a-stream-of-doubleproperty-as-a-doubleproperty).

The following code draws a `Circle` in an `AnchorPane`. The `Circle` is initialized with `centerX=centerY=radius=50`. When dragging mouse on the `Circle`, the `Circle` moves on the `AnchorPane`, such that its center coordinates remains at a constant position with respect to cursor position.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private final AnchorPane mainPane=new AnchorPane();

    double x=0,y=0;
    double tx =0, ty =0;

    int i=0;

    // create list with an extractor:
    ObservableList<Circle> circles =FXCollections.observableArrayList(circle1 -> new Observable[]{circle1.centerXProperty()});

    Circle circle = new Circle(50,50,50);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        // Set up stage for show!
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 1200, 800);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // set fill color.
        circle.setFill(new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5));

        // set up onMousePressed listener.
        circle.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            x=mouseEvent.getX();
            y=mouseEvent.getY();
        });

        // set up onMouseDragged listener.
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            tx=x;
            ty=y;
            x=mouseEvent.getX();
            y=mouseEvent.getY();
            circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX()+x-tx);
            circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()+y-ty);
            i++;
        });

        // add rectangle pane children.
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(circle);

        // add rectangle to rectangles.
        circles.add(circle);

        DoubleBinding centerX = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> circles
                        .stream()
                        .mapToDouble(Circle::getCenterX)
                        .min()
                        .orElse(0),
                circles
        );

        centerX.addListener((obs, oldMin, newMin) -> System.out.println("center X changed from " + oldMin + " to " + newMin+" , i = "+i));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

A custom `DoubleBinding centerX` tracks the changes in the centerX of the Circle and prints the following message on console:

`Min X changed from 50.0 to 58.0 , i = 0`

where `i` is an index [the numbers are arbitrary and may change].

This message printing continues well up to approximately `i=7000` and then stops. I would appreciate if someone gives me a hint as to why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks.

**Addendum**

The reason that I captured the `min()` of all `Circle` instances of circles is that I may have more than a `Circle` and I wish to capture the minimum position of the `centerX` values of these `Circle`s. I included only one `Circle` instance in this example for simplicity.

Comment: Tested the same code on `jdk1.8.0_341` and there was no problem, reached 21k.

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong That's a pretty out of date platform to test on.

Comment: You are running into the "premature garbage collection" problem. See linked Q&A. You can test this by adding `mainPane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.gc());`. Then clicking on the pane (not the circle) will cause the binding to stop working immediately. Fix it by making the binding an instance variable (so a reference to it is retained).